# How to refresh a dialog in odoo 8?

Tags: odoo-8

How can i reload the dialog on clicking a button?

```
@api.multi
def button(self):
    …
    ….signal_workflow('…')
    return True
```

This close the dialog

```
 @api.multi
 def button(self):
     …
     ….signal_workflow('…')
     return {
         'type': 'ir.actions.do_nothing',
     }
```

This doesn't close the dialog, but also doesn't refresh the dialog.

What is the correct way, to keep and refresh the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

I use this in the JS file

```
    ir_actions_act_refresh_dialog: function (action, options) {
        var widget = this.dialog_widget || this.dialog_new_widget || null;
        if(widget){
            widget.views[widget.active_view].controller.reload();
        }
        return $.when();
    },
```

and this in python

```
return {
    'type':  'ir.actions.act_refresh_dialog',
}
```